# Not able to add AddMicrosoftGraph in startup configure services .Net 5.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have added Nuget package MicrosoftGraph 3.24.0 in my project and  the `AddMicrosoftGraph` call in the startup configure services gets the below error.

Why?

##### Error

> 'MicrosoftIdentityAppCallsWebApiAuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftGraph' and no accessible extension method 'AddMicrosoftGraph' accepting a first argument of type 'MicrosoftIdentityAppCallsWebApiAuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have asp.net core project or console application?

Comment: @user2250152 I am using asp.net core project

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue?  I'm having he exact same issue;

Answer (score 20):

To use Graph API in asp.net core project you should add nuget `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph` (for v1.0) or `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphBeta` (for beta version).

In `ConfigureServices` add this:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Call `.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()` before `.AddMicrosoftGraph()`.

For .NET 6 when you create a new ASP.NEt Core Web App project select `Microsoft identity platform` authentication type.

[image]

Then create the project and you will be asked to install all required components.

[image]

In Program.cs add this:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you need to install the **same version** of the following NuGet libraries:

```
Microsoft.Identity.Web
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph
```

This is required because both use `Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition`.

### OPTIONAL: Configure GraphApi

In case you are using a `Startup` class, then add the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
  builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
}
```

In case you use C# Script to start the application, use the following code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;
/// Code from Startup.ConfigureServices ///

var app = builder.Build();
/// Code from Startup.Configure ///
app.Run();
```

You will need the following information in your `appsettings.json` file:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "ClientId": "<Guid>",
  "ClientSecret": "<Guid>",
  "TenantId": "<Guid>"
}
"GraphApi": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  "Scopes": "user.read"
}
```

### OPTIONAL: Use GraphApi

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "user.read" })]
    public async Task<string> SayMyName()
    {
        User user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        return user.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

I recommend having a look over: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph/TodoListService

Comment: Adding Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph were the packages that were missed that fixed it for me

Comment: Revisiting an old project, trying to uplift the packages from 1.251, I was having this same error. I was still getting it even though the upgraded packages were at same version. I ended up backing everything down to 1.25.1 and updating them to each version one at a time and making sure it could still compile, and it worked fine, eventually getting me to 2.11 successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues like this when trying to add Azure AD (Microsoft) authentication to my ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) web application.  Some of the code and project structure changed between .NET 5 and .NET 6, so I had a rough time trying to add these features in to my web application.

What I ended up having to do is create a brand new ASP.NET Core MVC web application project.  In the wizard, under **Authentication**, I chose the *Microsoft identity platform*, then I went through the rest of the Wizard.  Once the project loaded, I was able to go into the Program.cs file (.NET 6 got rid of Startup.cs), copy the code from that project and paste it into my existing web application project.  Then Microsoft authentication worked for me!  The generated code also included the call to *AddMicrosoftGraph* which is why I'm telling you all this now.

Trying to add this stuff into an existing application was horrendous due to Microsoft's documentation not being fully updated for .NET 6.  There was just so much documentation on .NET 5 and older, and .NET Framework.  It's amazing how creating a new project and having Visual Studio generate the code actually worked.  Usually it's just junk boilerplate code and files you don't need.

Comment: I'm in the same position; I can't figure out how to implement the .NET 6 version using only program.cs and no startup.cs

Comment: your suggestion/answer of creating a new project and letting the wizard add the code saved me from hours of more frustration, can't believe I didn't think of that!